# convert XML to PostgreSQL using MATLAB

Tags: xml, matlab, postgresql, postgis

In a weeks time I should be able to transfer the GIS data provided in the XML format to PostgreSQL database. I have prepared the PostgreSQL database (empty) and looking at Matlab scripts. (I am on ubuntu platform)

I am pretty new to the GIS data/table. Could you suggest me the steps in-detail to have the data in PostgreSQL?

Comment: You're generally better off asking this kind of thing on gis.stackexchange.com, but it's best to do some reading/research first if possible, and to be more specific about your needs. My first question in this case being "why matlab, what does it have to do with it?".

Comment: Hi Craig, Matlab is our existing platform. The work is passed on to me by another person who used Mapping tools on MATLAB to export the data to viewers like ArcGIS/Google Earth.This was created for a prototype. (However, in the final product I will be exporting PostgreSQL to QGIS to view the data).

Comment: It's impossible to answer this without more information, like what the XML data looks like. If it is in, say, GML or KML, then I'd recommend calling `ogr2ogr` shell commands. Otherwise, it's possible to parse XML and use a PostgreSQL database connection in pure MATLAB.